# Query repeats results several times

Tags: sql

So basically I'm new to SQL and queries and I want to all employees that have a badge colour Blue.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT   Employee.Employee_ID,
         Car_Registration,
         Badge.Badge_Colour,
         Start_Time,
         End_Time,
         Date_Issued,
         Booking_ID 
FROM     Employee,
         Vehicle,
         Badge,
         Booking 
WHERE    Employee.Employee_ID = Booking.Employee_ID 
AND      Badge.Badge_Colour = Employee.Badge_Colour 
AND      Badge.Badge_Colour = 'Blue'
```

Can anyone identify a problem with my query?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. –

Comment: You're missing a join on the Vehicle table.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.

Comment: this is called a cartesian product.

Comment: If you write your queries using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax, you will not have mismatched `JOIN` conditions.